# Call specific JavaScript function when specific item of h:selectOneMenu is selected

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsf-2

I have with ajax

```
<h:selectOneMenu>
<f:selectItem itemLabel="please click"/>
<f:selectItem itemLabel="1"/>
<f:selectItem itemLabel="2"/>
<f:ajax onevent="click()" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

I have with onChange

```
<h:selectOneMenu onChange="click()>
<f:selectItem itemLabel="please click"/>
<f:selectItem itemLabel="1"/>
<f:selectItem itemLabel="2"/>    
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

if I try the same attributes to selectItem, it doesnt work. I think they dont exist.

I used ajax, onChange but it seem to wrok for selectonemenu but not in particular for selectItem.

Comment: Your question is ambigious. You asked to fire an "action" which we understand to be a JSF managed bean action (or listener) method, but your code snippets instead attempt to fire a JavaScript function. Also, the presence of [javascript] tag on the question and explicit usage of on* attribute suggests that you want to do it client side rather than server side. What exactly do you want? Better yet, what problem/requirement exactly are you ultimately trying to solve and you thought that this all would possibly be the right solution?

Comment: I want to have an action on the client side by calling a js method. The code snippet works for the entire selectOneMenu ( select any items in the menu and js method is called). Instead i want to have different js methods to be called for different select items)

Comment: Why not just let the function check which item is currently being selected and then delegate further to the right task/function?  I fixed the question title and posted an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just pass the selected value to the JS function which in turn delegates further based on it.

```
<h:selectOneMenu onchange="foo(this.value)">
    ...
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

```
function foo(selectedValue) {
    switch (selectedValue) {
        case "1": bar(); break;
        case "2": baz(); break;
        // ...
    }
}
```